# How do you round a two decimal places in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, decimal

I am trying to round a number to 2 decemals and it is giving me integers!

```
var 4 = 10.99 + 89.78899999
total = number(a) + number(b);
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
Math.round(total, 2);  // this gives me 101 I need it to show 100.78
```

What is the trick to do this?

Comment: var 4 is an invalid name

Comment: Why did you think that [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) would give you decimal places?

Comment: As stated below you should probably use `Number.toFixed()` as Math.round only takes one parameter (the value to round) and rounds it to the nearest integer. Using `Math.round()` you'd have to do this to get two decimal places `Math.round(myNumber * 100) / 100)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) like with:

```
alert(12.432432.toFixed(2)); // 12.43
```

[`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)  is  for: *"Returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer."*

BTW, `4` isn't a valid variable name in javascript, it can't begin with a number.

[What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/601179)

Comment: Thanks uys gdoron that did it